# Good resources for learning about my STK500

Tags: avr

I have a Atmel STK500. And I can't get my head around what half of the board does. Does any one know of any good resources for learning about it. I have the following books:

[image]
[image]

The primer book is good with the STK500 but only talks about the mega16(I think I maybe wrong on that don't have it to hand). But then stops after the first couple of pages and tells you how to only program the one microcontroller with it. Is there anything else I can look at to use my STK500 to its full potential? And configuring the jumpers as they confuse me being a novice. I would like to program other microcontrollers from atmel with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the AVR Studio help files at `Help > AVR Tools User Guide` and click on the STK-500. It's the same files that come with the kit, but those are likely stuck on a CD-ROM somewhere in the sock drawer (mine certainly are). Pretty good info therein, anyway. If you're using Eclipse or something else, I can upload them or Google can reveal them.

Answer (score 1):

[AVRDude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_1.html) supports programming AVR microcontrollers via the STK500.

The STK500 appears to have many peripherals. You might want to look at projects like [avrlib](http://www.procyonengineering.com/embedded/avr/avrlib/docs/html/index.html/). Alternatively, you might choose to ignore the peripherals and focus on the basics.