# Beyond Arduino: AVR Programming Book for Beginner

Tags: arduino, avr, books

I've been using Arduino for awhile and now I'm interested in programming AVR microcontrollers without the Arduino framework.

What is a good reference for beginning AVR programming in C? A book is preferred, but online resources are also welcome.

I'm looking for something that will start with basic setup on a *NIX platform, start with examples and cover a number of core topics. Something similar to K&R, but oriented toward microcontrollers would work well.

(Related question: [Linux / Mac AVR Programming Suite?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/linux-mac-avr-programming-suite))

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/start-off-with-embedded-c-with-atmega32-atmega-avr-series http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8909/good-resources-for-learning-about-my-stk500 http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/resources-to-learn-about-the-avr-risc-architecture

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.dwelch.com/arduino/. No C programming, but I do use Linux, and it does get you out of the Arduino framework. It doesn't work with all the cards, though.  [LilyPad](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLilyPad), yes, [Pro Mini](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini), yes, but not the [Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and not the [Pro](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardPro).

Comment: fixed my loader to work with the uno and pro.

Comment: added a C programming example to the bottom of the web page.  Are you looking to learn the C programming language, or do you mean just not programming C in their sandbox/environment but good old command line linux.  The examples and loader program on the page I linked were compiled and loaded from a linux host.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Joe Pardue's C programming for microcontrollers at Smiley Micros

http://www.smileymicros.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=26&MMN_position=2:2

It has a windows bias but as it relies on WinAVR and therefore AVRdude it is easy to use from a nix perspective with the avr-gcc toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting book, for beginner, is [Make: AVR programming](http://makezine.com/2014/03/06/new-avr-programming-book-from-make/).
I liked it.

There is also a online repository for the book's code on [GitHub](https://github.com/hexagon5un/AVR-Programming).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. But just in case someone hit it for the same question. I learnt from a Cornell U online youtube video by Bruce Land, recorded in 2012 and was a very good lecture series.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT0xxaG1DhM

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as these link can become dead and the answer become useless.